# kinematic links use case?

Tags: gazebo-11

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello everybody!

I'm making some SDFs. I noticed that both the model and the link types support the  tag.

When referring to the model, I can understand the reasoning: you want to move this model by writing velocities to its base links or to each individual joint perhaps.

But having a kinematic link doesn't work as I would expect.

Expectation: The link has no weight (since its inverse inertia is set to 0 by the ODE implementation). You cannot apply a force to it. But if you fix it to the base link (with a fixed joint) it will follow the body base link hapily.

Reality: The (child) kinematic link is fixed in place if you don't write a velocity to it. Applying a force to the base link (where the child link is attached with a fixed joint) results in no motion, because the child link prevents the whole model from moving. This sounds a bit counter productive.

Is there a good use case for a kinematic link, which you couldn't do with a kinematic model?

Thank you for your time!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25950/kinematic-links-use-case?/) by [Georacer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2336/georacer/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 37 on 2020-10-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I love kinematic links, they're great for cheating/hacking things. For example, let's say I have a rope model and I want to pretend it's being held by at each end by some magical floating grippers. Instead of applying forces and a closed-loop controller to try to make the grasped points stay at some position or follow a trajectory, I can just make those *links* kinematic, and call SetWorldPose. If I do this, the rest of the rope will be dynamic and respect physics, but the fake-grasped-points will move kinematically.

What you expect is easily made exactly as  you describe -- just make a link (not kinematic) which has no mass and has a fixed joint to the base.

---

Originally posted by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) with karma: 768 on 2020-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Georacer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2336/georacer/) on 2020-10-15**:
So you're using them with a free ball joint. Great use case!

"What you expect is easily made exactly as you describe -- just make a link (not kinematic) which has no mass and has a fixed joint to the base."
I would expect applying a force to a zero-mass link to throw the solver out of whack, but I guess I'll find out soon enough.

Thanks!

**Comment by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) on 2020-10-26**:
another option is to merge the links. you can have multiple collision and or visual elements in one link

**Comment by [Georacer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2336/georacer/) on 2020-10-26**:
My intention wasn't to use the extra link as a collision carrier, but to actually help me get its local frame state and apply local wrenches, so merging wasn't an option.

**Comment by [danzimmerman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/41990/danzimmerman/) on 2021-02-11**:
This answer was super helpful. I'll come back when I have enough karma to upvote.

`<kinematic>` as a moveable boundary condition is really very useful.